# How to refresh a page or window in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I cannot seem to refresh or reload a parent window or page in wpf. I have tried the following:

```
private void btClear1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //this.LayoutUpdate();
     //Refresh();
     //this.NavigationService.Refresh(); 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by refreshing the window?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve complete layout/render pass with InvalidateVisual call (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx)