# How to refresh/reload a page after using method from windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a page that have a button to open a popup windows like this:

```
//in page.xaml.cs
   private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        New_Window window = new New_Window ();
        window .Show();
    }
```

Then in a popup New_Window, i want to close the popup window and reload the previous page after a click method in a popup window. How do i do it ? thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270371/how-to-refresh-a-page-or-window-in-wpf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I refresh window in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916521/how-do-i-refresh-window-in-wpf)